# Store Instance of Class in String

Tags: python, string, class

How can I store an instance of a class in a string? I tried `eval`, but that didn't work and threw `SyntaxError`. I would like this to work for user-defined classes and built-in classes (`int`, `str`, `float`).

Code:

```py
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

i = TestClass(14)
str_i = str(i)
print(eval(str_i)) # SyntaxError
print(eval("jkiji")) # Not Defined
print(eval("14")) # Works!
print(eval("14.11")) # Works!
```

Comment: What is the purpose of storing the instance?

Comment: [Avoid using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/5770501).

Comment: "How can I store an instance of a class in a string" Use *an actual object serialization format*. The fact that this works with most built-in types doesn't mean you should actually use it this way. Use `pickle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) built-in module to convert an object to a byte string and back:

```
import pickle

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

t1 = TestClass(14)
s1 = pickle.dumps(t1)
t2 = pickle.loads(s1)
```

then

```
print(t2.number)
```

will print

```
14
```

Answer (score 3):

The convention is to return a string with which you could instantiate the same object, if at all reasonable, in the `__repr__` method.

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.number})'
```

Demo:

```
>>> t = TestClass(14)
>>> t
TestClass(14)
>>> str(t)
'TestClass(14)'
>>> eval(str(t))
TestClass(14)
```

(Of course, [you should not actually use `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice/1832957#1832957) to reinstantiate objects in this way.)

Comment: yup, this is way that it is supposed to be done, but the user can pass their own classes (creating a very simple data structure using setattr and getattr)

Comment: @KetZoomer this is *definitely not the way it's supposed to be done*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yup, I know :)